# Problem forcing GNOME Terminal to stretch across multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-terminal

I am running `vim` in `gnome-terminal`, and ideally I would like to have fullscreen mode stretch across both monitors, not just one. Is there any way to do this? If I disable CCSM > Grid then I can stretch the terminal, but the results are less than ideal, observe:

[image]

Is there a way to fix the --I don't know what to call it exactly-- Z buffer problem at the top? If not, could someone point me in the direction of the source code so I could try to reverse engineer it to allow for dual monitor full screen mode?

Comment: +1, I'd love to be able to do this easily. Currently I just stretch the terminal.

Comment: @jrg it's doubly important for programs which are meant to only have one running instance, like vim.

Comment: Although, I do have to ask the question - why do you need so much text displayed? On my netbook I could display the quasi-standard 80 characters of text no problem with my little 10" display.

Comment: @jrg I split my vim session into 4-6 windows, and if I need more, I open different sessions, then I start opening the same file multiple times in different sessions, and all hell breaks loose ;-P

Comment: I take it you're using Unity?  I can't really see anything on your screenshot, but using Gnome classic, I can stretch it with no problems, while using Compiz Grid.  I can even set the terminal session to automatically open this way, if I want.

Comment: @MartyFried yes I am using unity. But have you found a way to stretch full screen across two windows :) ?

Comment: @puk: Well...  now that you mention it, I guess once I enter full screen, I can't, at least not with my current configuration.  It does seem that at one time, I had or thought I saw a way to configure one screen to span two monitors, but I won't swear to that.  However, if I auto-hide the panel, I can make it pretty close, though not as convenient - here's what I mean: [screenshot](http://imgur.com/7eFb4).  I guess I didn't fully understand your wish.  And I rarely use vim splits; I use buffers mostly, unless I want to compare (plus I use gvim).

Comment: @MartyFried I tried using gVim, but then switched back, It has too many flaws IMO

Comment: @puk: Really?  I assume you don't mean bugs - I don't think I've ever come across one.  The only reason I would not use gvim is if there is no gui available.  Otherwise, it's so much more flexible that I can't imagine using the terminal version.  But then, a lot of people can't even imagine using either one.  :)

Comment: @MartyFried things I dislike about gVim are: inferior shell (`:sh`), highlighting issue with mouse click+drag, lack of right click paste, unpredictable window load position with two monitors, no fullscreen mode. I don't think there are enough benefits to switch. 256 colors are more than enough, and I don't use the keymappings gVim allows for.

Comment: @puk: It's kind of funny that a half of your complaints are related to the mouse - I didn't know you could really use the mouse with terminal vim.  Anyway, I don't have most of those problems - guess I work differently or just have a different set of priorities.  We're lucky to be using an editor that adapts to both set of circumstances. :)

Comment: @MartyFried you're right, the mouse is rarely used. But the shell problem still exists. One can use ConqueTerm, but it has its problems too (ie. can't open vim from inside the shell). There's also no full screen (this is shameful). I just think there aren't enough benefits to overcome the, albeit few, setbacks.

Comment: The graphical corruption is a bug and should be reported against your video card drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug and you should [report the bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

At first glance it looks like a design bug, something somewhere should allow you to make a window go over multiple monitors. Like <kbd>F11</kbd> does for a single one.

But the second point is the corruption. Which looks very much like an error which should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If both screens are the same size then you shouldn't have a problem but I can't really think of another way and I also have the same problem I just use Jupiter for only my big monitor.

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Answer (score 1):

How is your math and your knowledge of XServer's xorg.conf?

You have to have both displays set at the same screen resolution, set up 2 separate distinct monitor sections. Then you create a virtual console screen that is the size of the two added together, then place the position of each monitor within that virtual console... Several ways to do that in xorg.conf, with one Device's GPU (having multiple outputs) or with multiple GPU's (seperate cards).

One example is, you have two monitors siting side-by-side. Each is set to 1024x768. You create a virtual console screen of 2048x768. You place the first monitor at 0,0. You place the other Monitor at 0,1025 or just "RightOf"

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier     "Monitor0"
  Option         "Primary"      "False"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier     "Monitor1"
  Option         "RightOf"      "Monitor0" 
  Option         "Primary"      "False"
  Option         "PreferedMode" "1024x768"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier     "Card"
  Driver         "vesa"
  Option         "Monitor-DVI-I-0"  "Monitor0" 
  Option         "Monitor-DVI-I-1"  "Monitor1" 
EndSectionEndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier          "Screen0"
  Device              "Card"
  Monitor             "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth        24
  SubSection "Display"
    Modes            "1024x768"
    Virtual          2048 768 
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

There is more detail than that and many alternate ways to separate it out to specific points/positons and devices, that also vary depending on your hardware... Some cards require that you split out the screen section and put it back together in a server layout section. But this is "close" as a summarized answer without knowing what you specifically are working with.

Comment: I'm hesitant to use this as I have had serious problems when editing `xorg.conf`. If I get a new computer I might try this, but as is, I am too worried of destroying my current settings